# unable to read dynamic components dd4t 1.3

Tags: dd4t, 2013-sp1

Hi i have upgraded my project from tridion 2011 sp1 dd4t 1.24 to tridion 2013sp1 dd4t 1.3. after upgrade my code is working fine with static pages and reed  component presentation but it throws null when try to  read dynamic component using below code

```
  public ViewResult Component(int publicationId, int componentId, string viewName)
        {
            TcmUri tcmUri = new TcmUri(publicationId, componentId, 16, 0);
            IComponent component;
            //IComponent c = ComponentFactory.GetComponent("tcm:71-23455-16", "tcm:71-23868-32");
            if (ComponentFactory.TryGetComponent(tcmUri.ToString(), out component))
            {
                return View(viewName, component);
            }
            // optionally throw exception in case component is not found
            return null;
        }
```

i have checked CT and component is published successfully in broker.

i have also tried getCompontnt mehtod

```
IComponent c = ComponentFactory.GetComponent(tcmUri.ToString(), tcmUrict.ToString());
```

but gives error

```
[ComponentNotFoundException: Error in the application.]
```

DD4T.Factories.ComponentFactory.GetComponent(String componentUri, String templateUri) +379
   Tourism.Web.Mvc.Controllers.ComponentController.Component(Int32 publicationId, Int32 componentId, String viewName) in c:\Websites\TourismNewFinal\Tourism.Web.Mvc\Controllers\ComponentController.cs:52
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +369
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +261
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.b__41() +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.b__33() +124
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.b__49() +837307
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.b__20() +33
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +837892
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +65
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +51
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +51
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3() +15
   System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Func`1 func) +41

> OR when i select **CT output format - HTML Fragment**
>   it gives below mentioned error

```
Line 51:             if (ComponentFactory.TryGetComponent(tcmUri.ToString(), out component))
```

Line 52:             {
Line 53:                 return View(viewName, component);

Source File: c:\Websites\TourismNewFinal\Tourism.Web.Mvc\Controllers\ComponentController.cs    Line: 51

Stack Trace:

[XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.]
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg) +195
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent() +7556193
   System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace) +176
   System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader) +144
   System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(String xml) +235
   DD4T.Factories.ComponentFactory.GetIComponentObject(String componentStringContent) +167
   DD4T.Factories.ComponentFactory.TryGetComponent(String componentUri, IComponent& component, String templateUri) +604
   Tourism.Web.Mvc.Controllers.ComponentController.Component(Int32 publicationId, Int32 componentId, String viewName) in c:\Websites\TourismNewFinal\Tourism.Web.Mvc\Controllers\ComponentController.cs:51
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +212
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +261
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.b__41() +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.b__33() +124
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.b__49() +837307
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.b__20() +33
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +837892
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +65
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +51
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +51

Answer (score 1):

You get an `XmlException` because the content of your DCP cannot be parsed as XML. Most likely this means your DCP is not a DD4T XML model.

I suggest to start with the database and look at the content of that DCP. I believe your CT is not a DD4T CT and such not producing the right XML for a DD4T model.

Comment: thanks mihai i have checked its DD4T CT with TBB'S Generate dynamic component and Publish binaries for component it seems fine.